# Dynamic Jquery management of multiple table rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic, html-table

Good Evening to all,

I'm currently developing an app that fetch data from a DB via AJAX calling a .php file.
I've got a table with 4 columns, the first 2 columns contain a < select >, the third an input and the last a button.

The first row is static: i've got a php query that loads the information of the 1st,2nd and 3rd column with default values.

When the user choose change the value of the 1st select a trigger launch a Jquery function that drop-down update the content of the 2nd and 3rd column.
In the same way if the user change the value of only the 2nd column, only the 3rd column value will be drop-down updated.

If the user make changes only with the 1st row, the code has no problem, but if the user press the button and via an .append() the code add another row, with the same scripts as the 1st one, obliviusly the new row selects won't work.

Trying to fix this I created a php for that copies the Jquery change functions using the iterator as identifier for both functions and the rows of the table.

Using the code inspector of chrome I don't find any errors, but only the 1st row jquery select will work, that is strange considerated that the 1st row function is generated by the same php cicle that is used for the others.

The hair are falling of my head because of this problem, hope you can understand and help me.

Thank in advance

Answer (score -1):

Events and handlers added to existing elements won't work on clones of those elements added later dynamically. Simply said, your functions to do stuff on drop-down etc on existing rows are limited to those only, and won't apply to any newly generated rows.

For a general solution, consider writing all the event handlers separately, and invoke those again when you add new rows on button click.

Hope this made sense!